# Are keycodes the same throughout all versions of firefox?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if keycodes for the newest version of Firefox are the same keycodes for the ones supported in Firefox version 31? If not, how would I find that key codes that are compatible with Firefox 31? (e.g. Numpad keycodes are numbers 96-105) I would like to add a keypress event when these buttons are pushed

Comment: It should not be different for firefox you be better off using `key` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: That might interest you : https://keycode.info/